# change grub setting from readonly to normal

Tags: grub2

Yesterday, I had installed Ubuntu Desktop in my system which already had Windows XP. After installation, when I restart the computer only Ubuntu is getting started as the timeout is set to 10 second only. And by the time my keyboard get unable the OS Ubuntu >get start up. Hence I try to change the timeout in in `/etc/default/grub`. But I am unable to change as it say it is write-protected. How do I change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the `sudo` command.

The `sudo` command, in a nutshell, allows you to run commands as the Superuser. In other words, it allows you to do WHATEVER you want with your pc. ***WARNING: SUDO IS NOT A TOY.***

Try opening a terminal and running the command `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. It will ask you for your password. Type it in. (Note that there will be no masking character, or any character for that matter). Then, it'll open GEdit with the ability to change that file.

*You can substitute any text editor in place instead of `gedit`*

---

There is also a graphical version of sudo, called `gksudo`. If you are more comfortable with ONLY GUI, hit Alt+F2 and type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.

---

To learn more about `sudo`, run `man sudo` in a command prompt.